# Go - How to decode/convert a txt file contains hex chars into readable string

Tags: json, nginx, go, hex, decoding

I've got a log file, where each line is a JSON. Due to some Nginx security reasons, the logs are being saved in a hexadecimal format (e.g. the char " will be converted to \x22). Here is an example of a JSON line:

```
 { "body_bytes_sent": "474", "params": {\x22device_id\x22: \x221234567890\x22} }
```

My goal:

1. Read the file line by line.
2. Convert each line to a readable format

   ```
   { "body_bytes_sent": "474", "params" : {"device_id": "1234567890"} }
   ```
3. Convert this string into a JSON object so I could manipulate it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strconv.Unquote` to convert the string to a normal one:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    // this is what your input string looks like...
    qs := "{\\x22device_id\\x22: \\x221234567890\\x22}"

    // now let's convert it to a normal string
    // note that it has to look like a Go string literal so we're
    // using Sprintf
    s, err := strconv.Unquote(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, qs))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)

    // just for good measure, let's see if it can actually be decoded.
    // SPOILER ALERT: It decodes just fine!
    var v map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &v); err != nil {
        panic(err)

    }
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uCPAW5TjdH)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! It does give me a solution for the case I described my question, but it does not solve the case when the string is a mix of valid and non-valid JSON. See my updated question. Thanks again! BTW, this happens because the nginx encode only the request body params.

Comment: @Asaf: Why shouldn't Not_a_Golfer's code fail on the "mix of valid and non-valid JSON"?

Comment: If I run @Not_a_Golfer 's code, I get the error "invalid syntax" on this line `s, err := strconv.Unquote(fmt.Sprintf("%s", qs))`

Comment: @Asaf are you sure you're using the backticks properly? stack overflow might treat them badly

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Well, I think so.. :\ If you can confirm that my new example (updated in my question) is working with your code, I'll try looking again the wrong backticks.

Comment: @asaf not it's not... I'd try to just fix the data, but you can cteate your own unquote function

Comment: So I took @Not_a_Golfer advise, and added the line: `qs = strings.Replace(qs, "\"", "\\x22", -1)` in order to make his solution complete for my needs.